# What is the limit of results that are returned for List-user API call in Microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I could not find any mention of the limit of results that are returned for List user api call in microsoft graph api?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the limit results is 1000. We can use $top=1000 to test, it will throw the error: 'Invalid page size specified: '1000'. Must be between 1 and 999 inclusive.'

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=1000
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will try this and update the thread with the outcome.

Comment: This is what I found on Microsoft's site:

GET /users method supports the OData Query Parameters to help customize the response

Directory resources, such as device, group and user, currently limit the total number of schema extension property values that can be set on a resource instance, to 100.